# file upload within a wizard in primefaces - uploaded file does not showing up?

Tags: jsf, netbeans, primefaces, nested-forms

I use the Primefaces manual example for a wizard, and replace one of the tabs by a simple file upload form. I have all the necessary libraries and filter in web-inf for the file upload to work. Running the project with Netbeans does not show any error (the wizard is displayed and the UI responds), but the file is not uploaded and I get no system message from my fileBean class. Any clue where I make a mistake? Is something wrong with my nested form in the index.html? Thx!

index.xhtml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>The rings of scholarship</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>

            <p:growl id="growl" sticky="true" showDetail="true"/>

            <p:wizard widgetVar="wiz"
                      flowListener="#{userWizard.onFlowProcess}">

                <p:tab id="personal" title="Personal">

                    <p:panel header="Personal Details">

                        <h:messages errorClass="error"/>

                        <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, value" styleClass="grid">
                            <h:outputText value="Firstname: *" />
                            <p:inputText required="true" label="Firstname"
                                         value="#{userWizard.user.firstname}" />

                            <h:outputText value="Lastname: *" />
                            <p:inputText required="true" label="Lastname"
                                         value="#{userWizard.user.lastname}" />

                            <h:outputText value="Age: " />
                            <p:inputText value="#{userWizard.user.age}" />

                            <h:outputText value="Skip to last: " />
                            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{userWizard.skip}" />
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:panel>
                </p:tab>

                <p:tab id="upload" title="File upload">
                    <p:panel header="File upload">

                        <h:messages errorClass="error"/>

                        <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, value">
                            <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <p:fileUpload value="#{fileBean.file}" mode="simple" />
                                <p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{fileBean.save}" ajax="false"/>
                            </h:form>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                        <h:outputText value="Skip to last: " />
                        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{userWizard.skip}" />
                    </p:panel>
                </p:tab>

                <p:tab id="contact" title="Contact">
                    <p:panel header="Contact Information">

                        <h:messages errorClass="error"/>

                        <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, value">
                            <h:outputText value="Email: *" />
                            <p:inputText required="true" label="Email"
                                         value="#{userWizard.user.email}" />

                            <h:outputText value="Phone: " />
                            <p:inputText value="#{userWizard.user.phone}"/>

                            <h:outputText value="Additional Info: " />
                            <p:inputText value="#{userWizard.user.info}"/>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:panel>
                </p:tab>

                <p:tab id="confirm" title="Confirmation">
                    <p:panel header="Confirmation">

                        <h:panelGrid id="confirmation" columns="6">
                            <h:outputText value="Firstname: " />
                            <h:outputText styleClass="outputLabel"
                                          value="#{userWizard.user.firstname}" />

                            <h:outputText value="Lastname: " />
                            <h:outputText  styleClass="outputLabel"
                                           value="#{userWizard.user.lastname}"/>

                            <h:outputText value="Age: " />
                            <h:outputText styleClass="outputLabel"
                                          value="#{userWizard.user.age}" />>

                            <h:outputText value="Email: " />
                            <h:outputText styleClass="outputLabel"
                                          value="#{userWizard.user.email}" />

                            <h:outputText value="Phone " />
                            <h:outputText styleClass="outputLabel"
                                          value="#{userWizard.user.phone}"/>

                            <h:outputText value="Info: " />
                            <h:outputText styleClass="outputLabel"
                                          value="#{userWizard.user.info}" />

                            <h:outputText />
                            <h:outputText />
                        </h:panelGrid>

                        <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="growl" 
                                         actionListener="#{userWizard.save}"/>

                    </p:panel>
                </p:tab>

            </p:wizard>

        </h:form>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

fileBean:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class FileBean implements Serializable{

    private UploadedFile file;
/**
 * Creates a new instance of FileBean
 */
public FileBean() {
}

public UploadedFile getFile() {
    System.out.println("we get file");
    return file;
}

public void setFile(UploadedFile file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    System.out.println("we set file");
    this.file = file;

}

public void save() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("we save file");
    IOUtils.copy(file.getInputstream(), new FileOutputStream("D:\\" + file.getFileName()));
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file.getInputstream()));
    String currLine = br.readLine();
    Integer counterLines = 0;
    while (currLine != null && counterLines < 5) {
        System.out.println("currLine is: " + currLine);
        counterLines++;
    }

}
```

}

UserWizard:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import org.primefaces.event.FlowEvent;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class UserWizard implements Serializable{

    private User user = new User();
    private boolean skip;
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserWizard.class.getName());

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public void save(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        //Persist user

        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Successful", "Welcome :" + user.getFirstname());
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }

    public boolean isSkip() {
        return skip;
    }

    public void setSkip(boolean skip) {
        this.skip = skip;
    }

    public String onFlowProcess(FlowEvent event) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Current wizard step:{0}", event.getOldStep());
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Next step:{0}", event.getNewStep());

        if (skip) {
            skip = false;   //reset in case user goes back
            return "confirm";
        } else {
            return event.getNewStep();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by getting rid of the nested forms... you got one surrounding the wizard and one inside the `<p:tab id="upload" title="File upload">`

Try removing the inner form from the tab and wrap the wizard with `<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: thx @Daniel, but I thought the <form> tag (and its "multipart/form-data") was necessary for the file upload? How should I get rid of nested forms and still get a fileupload inside a wizard?

Comment: place simple `<h:form>` in each tab (except the tab with the upload) and place `<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">` in the tab with the upload...

Comment: I tried but then I get an error msg saying that the wizard primefaces tag itself should be enclose in a form... (this would again created a nested form situation). Any further idea? @Daniel

Comment: so try removing the inner form from the tab and wrap the wizard with `<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: also what version of primefaces are you using ? http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=1891

Comment: your latest suggestion worked! Could you edit your answer to include your comment in it? Thanks a lot for your help! @Daniel

Comment: b.t.w what suggestion exactly helped ? "removing the inner form from the tab and wrap the wizard with <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">" Or the link to the issue saying "upgrade your pf version" ?"

Comment: @seinecle Your edit was reject by others (That weren't aware of the need to edit my original answer :) ) , I saw your edit and copy paste into my answer...